# Question related to sequences of the form $\{n \sqrt{b}\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Here, $\{\}$ denotes fractional part function.

I created this exercise:

Choose some two different positive integers that are not squares and call them $a$ and $b$.

For some choice of $a$ and $b$ we can define two sequences: $c(n)=\{n \sqrt{a}\}$ and $d(n)=\{n \sqrt{b}\}$. Further, sequence $e(n)$ can de defined as $e(n)=c(n)-d(n)$,

It seems to me that whatever $a$ and $b$ we choose that $e(n)$ will change sign an infinite number of times.

> Is that true?

Answer (score 2):

If $\sqrt a$, $\sqrt b$, and $\sqrt{a/b}$ are all irrational, the sequence $(c(n),d(n))$ is dense in the torus $\mathbb T^2 = \mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2$, so yes, $e(n)$ will change signs infinitely often. This and much more follows from [Kronecker's and Weyl's equidistribution theorems](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/notes_2013-14/04_Fourier-Weyl).  (See 2.0.2 and 3.2.1 in the linked paper.)

More generally, the sequence $(c(n),d(n))$ is equidistributed in the closed subgroup $G$ in $\mathbb T^2$ generated by $(\sqrt a,\sqrt b)$, whatever that is.  Unless $G$ is a subgroup of the image of $\mathbb T$ under the map $t\mapsto (t,t)$ (which cannot happen under the condition that $a$ and $b$ are distinct non-squares), the sequence $e(n)$ will change sign infinitely often.

Comment: What about if $\sqrt{a/b}$ is not irrational? I feel like the sequence should still be dense in this case also.

Comment: Try plotting the first 1000 or so points when  $a=3$ and $b=12$.  You will find all the points $(c(n),d(n))$ lie on a 1 dimensional subgroup of the torus.

Comment: Is there anything we can say in this case?

Comment: Yes, implicit in my previous comment.  Why don't you study the paper I cited in my answer, and see if you can guess how Weyl would have answered your question?

Comment: I'm already familiar with this paper, but I'm wondering if you know how to answer the original question in the case where $\sqrt{a/b}$.  Lying on a one dimensional subgroup doesn't imply that $e(n)$ changes signs only finitely often, in fact I suspect the condition that $\sqrt{a/b}$ can be omitted from your answer.

Comment: @B.Mehta Your first feeling was that if $\sqrt{a/b}$ was rational, the orbit would be dense in the torus.  This is not the case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70650/discussion-between-b-mehta-and-kimchi-lover).